# SQL to mongodb conversion

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two fields in mongodb, `A` and `B`

I would like to perform the following sql query in mongo

```
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM table WHERE B LIKE 'asdf'
```

EDIT for clarification

```
foo ={
    bar: [{
            baz:[
                ‘one’,
                ‘two'
            ]
        },{...}
    ]
}
```

I would like to select distinct foo objects where `bar.baz` contains ‘one’.  
The query:

```
db.runCommand({
    "distinct": "foo",
    "query": {
        “bar.baz": “one"
    },
    "key": “bar.baz"
});
```

This query, oddly enough, returns foo objects who's `bar.baz` /doesnt/ contain ‘one’.

Comment: In your SQL, "A" is a table name, not a field. Did you mean to type something else?

Comment: fixed. thanks for pointing that mistake out

Comment: the question I posted was a simplification. Please see the more elaborate question

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here of how the MongoDB distinct command works or indeed how any query works with arrays.

I am going to consider that you actually have documents that look something like this:

```js
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5398f8bf0b5d1b43d3e26816"),
    "bar" : [
        {
            "baz" : [
                "one",
                "two"
            ]
        },
        {
            "baz" : [
                "three"
            ]
        },
        {
            "baz" : [
                "one",
                "four"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So the query that you have run, and these two forms are equivalent:

```js
db.runCommand({ 
    "distinct": "foo", 
    "query": { "bar.baz": "one" }, 
    "key": "bar.baz" 
})

db.foo.distinct("bar.baz", { "bar.baz": "one" })
```

Returns essentially this:

```js
[ "four", "one", "three", "two" ]
```

Why? Well, because you asked it to. Let's consider a declarative way of describing what you actually invoked.

Your "query" essentially says *'Find me all the "documents" that have "bar.baz" equal to "one" '* then you are asking *'And return me all of the "distinct" values for "bar.baz"*

So the "query" part of your statement does exactly that, and matched "documents" and not array members that match the value you specified. In the above example you are then asking for the "distinct" values of "bar.baz", which is exactly what you get, with there only being the value of "one" returned once from all of the values of "bar.baz".

So "query" statements do not "filter" array contents they just "match" where the condition exists. The above document matches the condition and "bar.baz" has a value of  "one", and twice even. So selecting the distinct "foo" or basically the document is really:

```js
db.foo.find({ "bar.baz": "one" })
```

Matching all documents that meet the condition. This is how embedding works, but perhaps you wanted something like filtering the results. So looking at returning only those items of "bar" whose "baz" has a value of "one" you would do:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Matches documents
    { "$match": { "bar.baz": "one" } },

    // Unwind to de-normalize arrays as documents
    { "$unwind": "$bar" },

    // Match to "filter" documents without "bar.baz" matching "one"
    { "$match": { "bar.baz": "one" } },

    // Maybe group back to document with the array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "bar": { "$push": "$bar" }
    }}

])
```

The result of this [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) statement is the document without the member of "bar" that does not contain "one" under "baz":

```js
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5398f8bf0b5d1b43d3e26816"),
    "bar" : [
        {
            "baz" : [
                "one",
                "two"
            ]
        },
        {
            "baz" : [
                "one",
                "four"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But then suppose you actually want just the element "bar.baz" equal to "one" and the total count of those occurrences over your whole collection, then you would want to do this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Matches documents
    { "$match": { "bar.baz": "one" } },

    // Unwind to de-normalize arrays as documents
    { "$unwind": "$bar" },

    // And the inner array as well
    { "$unwind": "$bar.baz" },

    // Then just match and filter out everything but the matching items
    { "$match": { "bar.baz": "one" } },

    // Group to get the count
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$bar.baz",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}

])
```

And from our single document collection sample you get:

```js
{ "_id": "one", "count": 2 }
```

As there are two occurrences of that matching value.

---

As for your SQL at the head of your question, that really doesn't apply to this sort of data. The more practical example would be something with data like this:

```js
{ "A": "A", "B": "BASDFJJ" }
{ "A": "A", "B": "ASDFTT" }
{ "A": "B", "B": "CASDF" }
{ "A": "B", "B": "DKITB" }
```

So the "distinct" values of "A" where "B" is like "ASDF", again using aggregate and noting you are not wildcarding on either side:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "B": "ASDF" } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$A" } }
])
```

Which essentially produces:

```js
{ "_id": "A" }
```

Or with wildcards on either side "%ASDF%" this is a [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query to match:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "B": { "$regex": "ASDF" } } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$A" } }
])
```

So only two results:

```js
{ "_id": "A" }
{ "_id": "B" }
```

Where if you were "counting" the distinct matches then you would see 2 and 1 as the counts respectively according to the documents that matched.

Take a further look at the [SQL Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) and the [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) contained within the documentation. It should help you in understanding how common actions actually translate.